# Laravel Eloquent orWhere Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

Can someone show me how to write this query in Eloquent?

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `id`='17' OR `id`='19'
```

I am thinking

```
Project::where('id','=','17')
        ->orWhere('id','=','19')
        ->get();
```

Also my variables (17 and 19) in this case are coming from a multi select box, so basically in an array. Any clues on how to cycle through that and add these where/orWhere clauses dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could do in three ways. Assume you've an array in the form

`['myselect' => [11, 15, 17, 19], 'otherfield' => 'test', '_token' => 'jahduwlsbw91ihp']` which could be a dump of `\Input::all();`

1. ```
      Project::where(function ($query) {
         foreach(\Input::get('myselect') as $select) {
            $query->orWhere('id', '=', $select);
         }
      })->get();
   ```
2. ```
      Project::whereIn('id', \Input::get('myselect'))->get();
   ```
3. ```
      $sql = \DB::table('projects');
      foreach (\Input::get('myselect') as $select) {
          $sql->orWhere('id', '=', $select);
      }
      $result = $sql->get();
   ```

Comment: What would happen to 3 if there's already a where statement before the loop?

Answer (score 17):

The best approach for this case is using Laravel's equivalent for SQL's `IN()`.

```
Project::whereIn('id', [17, 19])->get();
```

Will be the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN (17, 19)
```

This approach is nicer and also more efficient - according to the [Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), if all values are constants, `IN` sorts the list and then uses a binary search.

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 5 you could do it this way.

```
$projects = Projects::query();

foreach ($selects as $select) {
    $projects->orWhere('id', '=', $select);
}

$result = $projects->get();
```

This is very useful specially if you have custom methods on your Projects model and you need to query from variable. You cannot pass `$selects` inside the orWhere method.

Comment: What would happen if there's already a where statement before the loop? Wouldn't it be invalidated since the loop already starts with an OR

Comment: AFAIK Yes it will be invalidated

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getSearchProducts($searchInput)
    {
        $products = Cache::rememberForever('getSearchProductsWithDiscountCalculationproducts',  function () {
            return DB::table('products_view')->get();
        });

        $searchProducts = $products->filter(function ($item) use($searchInput)  {
            return preg_match('/'.$searchInput.'/i', $item->productName) || preg_match('/'.$searchInput.'/i', $item->searchTags) ;
        });

         $response = ["status" => "Success", "data" => $searchProducts ];
        return response(json_encode($response), 200, ["Content-Type" => "application/json"]);
    }
```

**use filter functionality for any customize situations.**