# Multiple column with same search string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    CONCAT(id,name, address) LIKE '%same_string%'
```

What is an alternate query for this in `Laravel`

Comment: You can adapt this to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632236/laravel-eloquent-orwhere-query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
$field = ['name','id','address'];
$name = DB::Table('bookinfo')->Where(function ($query) use($string, $field) {
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($field); $i++){
                $query->orwhere($field, 'like',  '%' . $string .'%');
             }      
        })->get();
```

Comment: this is not working with concat function. Return NULL from DB.

Comment: I think this code will successfully executed but I need a good structured code like mysql query.

Comment: Needs to access each $i of $field `$query->orwhere($field[$i], 'like'`

Answer (score 4):

**
    **Laravel**
 - ***The general search in multiple columns the in single input***

**

one of the user table in the first name, last name, job title column available and I have one input search in any value enter then find all column in associated data fetch and display

```
 $searchQuery = trim($request->query('search'));
 $requestData = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'job_title'];
  $user = User::where(function($q) use($requestData, $searchQuery) {
                        foreach ($requestData as $field)
                           $q->orWhere($field, 'like', "%{$searchQuery}%");
                })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **separate column**

```
DB::table("table_name")->whereRaw(" (`id` like ? or `name` like ? or `address` like ? ) ",["%".$same_string."%","%".$same_string."%","%".$same_string."%"])->get();
```