# Assign where clause to a variable so that in can be used based on condition

Tags: laravel

I have the following code placed below which i wish to be written in laravel way. Please help me with this.

I have writing it this way but it doesn't work.

```
if (isset($request->search)) {
            $WHERE = ' WHERE project_name LIKE "%'.$request->search.'%" OR email LIKE "%'.$request->search.'%"';
        } else {
            $WHERE = NULL;
        }
        if(isset($request->offset) && isset($request->limit)){
            $sql = DB::select('SELECT id, project_name, email, phone, company, price FROM records "'.$WHERE.'" ORDER BY id LIMIT "'.$request->offset.'","'.$request->limit.'"');
        }else{
            $sql = DB::select('SELECT id, project_name, email, phone, company, price FROM records ORDER BY id');
        }
```

Below is the actual php code i want to be rewritten in Laravel way. Please, Help me with this.

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
            $WHERE = ' WHERE vehicle_id LIKE "%'.$_GET['search'].'%" ';
        } else {
            $WHERE = NULL;
        }

        if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){
            $sql = "SELECT vehicle_id, deviceImei, locationAddress, ward_no FROM gps_locations ".$WHERE." ORDER BY sl_no LIMIT ".$_GET['offset'].",".$_GET['limit']."";
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT vehicle_id, deviceImei, locationAddress, ward_no FROM gps_locations ORDER BY sl_no";
        }

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $a_json_row["Vehicle_Id"] = $row["vehicle_id"];
                $a_json_row["DeviceImei"] = $row["deviceImei"];
                $a_json_row["LocationAddress"] = $row["locationAddress"];
                $a_json_row["WardNo"] = $row["ward_no"];
                array_push($temp, $a_json_row);
                //echo "id: " . $row["user_id"]. " - Name: " . $row["user_name"]. "<br>";
            }
        }
        //return print_r($temp);
        $sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM gps_locations ".$WHERE."";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        $data = $result2->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel you can do this easily with Query Builder.. like for the php code you write.

**PHP**

```
if (isset($request->search)) {
    $WHERE = ' WHERE project_name LIKE "%'.$request->search.'%" OR email LIKE "%'.$request->search.'%"';
} else {
    $WHERE = NULL;
}
if(isset($request->offset) && isset($request->limit)){
    $sql = DB::select('SELECT id, project_name, email, phone, company, price FROM records "'.$WHERE.'" ORDER BY id LIMIT "'.$request->offset.'","'.$request->limit.'"');
}else{
    $sql = DB::select('SELECT id, project_name, email, phone, company, price FROM records ORDER BY id');
}
```

**In Laravel**

```
$qb = DB->table("records")->select("id", "project_name", "phone", "company", "price");

if (isset($request->search)) {
    $qb = $qb->where("project_name", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%")
             ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%". $request->search."%");
}

 $result = $qb->orderBy("id", "ASC")->get(); // it would return laravel collection. so just dd() and see the structure.

//....
//....

foreach($result as $row){
    dd($row->id); // it will print the id.
}
```

Here you can find the guide about how should get started with building Query in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects

**IF you would like to share the condtions across multiple query builder do follow this.**

```
$whereData = [];
$orWhereData = [];

if (isset($request->search)) {
    $whereData = [
            ["project_name", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%"]
    ];

    $orWhereData = [
            ["email", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%"]
    ];
}

 $result = DB->table("records")
                ->select("id", "project_name", "phone", "company", "price")
                ->where($whereData)
                ->orWhere($orWhereData)
                ->orderBy("id", "ASC")
                ->get(); // it would return laravel collection. so just dd() and see the structure.

//....
//....

foreach($result as $row){
    dd($row->id); // it will print the id.
}


// for the gps_locations.

$total = DB::table("gps_locations")
                ->where($whereData)
                ->orWhere($orWhereData)
                ->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. And it works as well. But, how do i do the Count part i want the same Where clause there as shown here: ``` $sql2 = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM gps_locations ".$WHERE."";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2); ```

Comment: @user2871257 please check `IF you would like to share the condtions across multiple query builder do follow this.` section... updated solution for that case.

Comment: Let me know if it helpful?

Comment: Thank you very much its working absolutely fine. By the way if i want to add more in where clause. Should i add another variable like $orWherename = [
            ["name", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%"]
    ];

Comment: Just push another values(array) in your $orWhereData or $whereData depends on your application business logic. No need to declare another variable.. you can use existing one.

Comment: You mean this way.. $orWhereData = [
                ["email", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%"],
                ["phone", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%"]
            ];   Its not working

Comment: Its is not taking the phone column in search filter

Comment: its is not executing the rest of the code when i search. its happening o0nly after pushing phone column in $orWhereData array

Comment: If you would like to build a search query on multple fields... why not you are trying this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125793/multiple-column-with-same-search-string-in-laravel

Comment: Just define this as external funcion and try on both of the places... `function ($query) use($string, $field) {
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($field); $i++){
                $query->orwhere($field[$i], 'like',  '%' . $string .'%');
             }      
        }`

Comment: it works with separate variable $orWhereName = [
                ["phone", "LIKE", "%".$request->search."%"]
            ];    For this i have to put another orWhere in the query builder.. otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: ok i got it. if i push another in $orWhereData array then where clause in query puts AND instead of OR. Whereas, i need only OR in where clause. So to do that i had to declare different arrays and use orWhere() numerous times. well it works. But, is there any better solution than this.

Comment: If you have to search across multiple fields you can just try this approach. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125793/multiple-column-with-same-search-string-in-laravel`

Comment: But for the better visiblity of code you should have to specify the conditions separatly for each querybuilder... so it could be more readable. Don't worry about the duplicacy in such case.

Comment: Also for group two or more conditions that you feel need to be used frequenty... you can use Laravel Model Scopes.