# How to search a string in database tables and retrieve matched columns name in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a table having below column.
Title, subtitle, series, blurs, keyword_one, keyword_two, keyword_three, keyword_four, keyword_five, keyword_six, keyword_seven,

Now I want to search a “word” … or a string then retrieve 2 things (1) title and (2) column in which found that string or word……

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52125823/7808950

Comment: or simply use 
->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") 
->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%")

Comment: Without any code example provided, approach would be to create eloquent query that will find all the rows where one of the `keyword_*` column matches "word". You can use the `->where()` and `->orWhere()` example that @MahmoudGad provided. Once you have the resulting collection you can use [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-map) on the resulting collection to return only the properties that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best answer, but you could do something like:

```
DB::table('table')->selectRaw('`title`, @word:="%word_to_search%", CASE WHEN `subtitle` LIKE @word THEN 'subtitle' WHEN `series` LIKE @word THEN 'series' WHEN `blurs` LIKE @word THEN 'blurs' WHEN `keyword_one` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_one' WHEN `keyword_two` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_two' WHEN `keyword_three` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_three' WHEN `keyword_four` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_four' WHEN `keyword_five` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_five' WHEN `keyword_six` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_six' WHEN `keyword_seven` LIKE @word THEN 'keyword_seven' END AS `column`')->get();
```

I used the @word variable for the sake of simplification.