# how to make orWhere undefined?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm new to Php and I'm stuck in this.

I need to make a category filter, which is selected with a checkbox.
How could an orWhere do for each category?

I need something like:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                 -> where ('category_id', 1)
                 -> orWhere ('category_id', 2)
                ...
                -> orWhere ('category_id', n)
                 -> get ();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent orWhere Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632236/laravel-eloquent-orwhere-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `whereIn` to get multiple id's**

please pass proper use  variable `$users` insted of `$ users`

**edit your question like this**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->where('category_id', 1)
                 -> orWhere ('category_id', 2)
                  ...
                 -> orWhere ('category_id', n)
                 -> get ();
```

**Try THis**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
              ->whereIn("category_id" , [1,2,...,n])
              ->get();
```

Comment: mark as verified if its help for you so other can refer this answer Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
              ->whereIn("category_id" , [1,2,...,n])
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use whereIn:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```